# What is the difference between var x=10 and x=10 when typed in browser console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In browser console if I type `var x=10` it shows `undefined` while if i type `x=10` it shows `10`. Both perform the same task then what is the difference?
I am not asking difference between using var and not using var?

Comment: Nothing... `x=10` will return the value so 10 is printed in the console... when you say `var x=10`, no value is returned that is why `undefined` is printed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in browser console, so you are alerady in global scope, and with or without var make no difference on how the variable was stored:

[image: Prove]

However, `=` is a operator which **return**s the value you assigned, so `a = 1` will evaluate to 1, and you see a `2` when you typed `b = 2`. `var` don't return anything, it is a statement not an expression.

Comment: Perhaps some references: [*assignment runtime semantics*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation)—assignment expression returns the right hand value. [*variable declaration runtime semantics*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-variable-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation)—if successful, returns *undefined*.

Answer (score 3):

EXPLANATION

case `x = 10`:

This creates a variable in the Global scope named `x` with value `10`.
Additionally, this is an expression, which returns the value `10`. This is useful in order to be able to do things like `var x = y = 10;` which sets both `x` and `y` to the value `10`

case `var x = 10`:

This creates a variable in the current scope, which just so happens to be
the global scope, named `x` with value `10`. Because it is created with the 
syntax `var`, it cannot be evaluated as an expression, therefore it returns `undefined`, which is printed to the console.

SUMMARY

There is no difference in effect of writing `var x = 10` vs `x = 10` from the console, although there will be in other places. The latter is also not allowed in strict mode. However the first returns `undefined` because when run, there is no output, however the second returns `10` because `x=10` is an expression.

EXAMPLE

You can see what is happening a little better if you use `eval`

```
var output = eval('x = 10');  
console.log(output)           // 10
```

vs

```
var output = eval('var x = 10');  
console.log(output)           // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

If var is used within a function or other non-global scope then the variable is not a global variable. If var is not used before a variable name, then you have created a global variable.

/

```
/ These are both globals
var foo = 1;
bar = 2;

function()
{
    var foo = 1; // Local
    bar = 2;     // Global

    // Execute an anonymous function
    (function()
    {
        var wibble = 1; // Local
        foo = 2; // Inherits from scope above (creating a closure)
        moo = 3; // Global
    }())
}
```

If you're not doing an assignment then you need to use var:

```
var x; // Declare x
```

Comment: Right. Except this question is about why the browser console prints what it does when you enter the two different lines *into the console*.

Comment: this is not what i asked

Answer (score 1):

Scenario 1 :

See Basically when you are typing x = 10 on browser console you're getting 10 because 10 is an int value being returned by browser console.

Scenario 2 : 
And When you are typing var x = 10 on browser console you're getting "undefined" because it displays the return value of each command and console doesn't return anything  in this scenario.

And Further For more Reference Visit Here  :

http://blog.modulus.io/absolute-beginners-guide-to-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

var x = 10; sets the value for the current scope( inside function as example).

x = 10; sets the value for the global scope, so it's accessible everywhere.

Comment: I know, but that doesn't matter. You can also input functions inside the console with variables. In this case the browser console scope is the same as the global scope so it doesn't matter.

Comment: You've missed the point of the question. OP is asking why the console responds with "undefined" in one case and "10" in the other.

Comment: i am not asking writing var inside a function or outside a function my concern was why console respond with different output

Answer (score 0):

```
// they both define var x and set it value to 10,but they are diff about below

// x is globally
x = 10

// x is scopely
var x = 10
```

In browser env, globally mean var is define as the Object `window`'s property

**But be careful about using the first code, it can cause global define variable.**

And if it in `strict mode`,**this will not work**, because the **Implicitly defined** global is not allow.

Comment: The OP understands what the two versions do, and about scope. The question is about why when those lines are entered *into the console* the console gives different responses.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information on the difference apart from mentioned above:

```
var x=10;
x=10;
```

There is a difference in terms of property descriptor which gets created
when you write `var x=10;` you can't delete `x` because configurable will be false for this `x`
On the other hand `x=10;` you can delete `x` because configurable will be true for this `x`

e.g.

```
var a="UnDeletable";
delete a; //Prints false
console.log(a);//Prints UnDeletable
```

Open new browser console don't write below statement in the same console otherwise it will use same a used before and same property descriptor will be used i.e. configurable false

```
a="Deletable";
delete a;//Prints true
console.log(a);//Reference error..a is not defined
```